# Creating Content Provider using Xamarin Platform

Tags: xamarin, shared-libraries, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, portable-class-library

I am using Xamarin cross-platform for the development of an application. At this moment, my goal is to develop it for Android OS. But future goal also consists of using the same code(with some modifications) for Windows phone application.

I have to create a database and make it available to other applications. I am planning on using Content Provider(android specific) in my app. My question here is where do I write the code for Content Provider - android space or common code space ?

Should I use Shared Library or Portable Class Library for this type of development ?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, `ContentProvider` is an Android thing, so you would have to implement that in an Android app project or in an Android Library project, and this would not be cross platform and usable by a Windows app of any sort. 

I might suggest not using a ContentProvider but just using an sqlite database to store your data. This could be used in a cross platform manner, though some platform specific code would be needed as well. This guide may help:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/

Comment: @jgoldberger : Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, Content Provider is platform specific. But how can I make the data available to other applications if I don't use content provider ? Because at this moment I am creating it for Android OS

Comment: If you need to make the data available to other Android apps, then yes, use ContentProvider. This can still draw it's data from a source that you could use x-plat, IOW your Android app or Android library could derive the data for the ContentProvider from a model class that can be used x-plat. If you later develop for iOS and Windows phone, you would then have to use the native methods on those platforms to deliver the data to other apps, while still deriving said data from your x-plat model.

Comment: @jgoldberger : Thanks for your suggestion. I am going with Content Provider